# Flash player redirect issues in Microsoft Edge

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, redirect, server, microsoft-edge

For some reason Microsoft Edge's flash player doesn't properly load urls with redirects.

I'm trying to load a file from CDN using urlLoader.load(). I make a request to https://cdn.example.com/path/name and server redirects me to https://edge-01.example.com/path/name with HTTP 302.

In other browsers everything works fine. I can get the file and see two crossdomain requests (for CDN and edge-01). In case of MS Edge I can only see crossdomain request for CDN. Redirected request to edge-01 stucks and in a minute returns HTTP 408.

Any ideas or workarounds on this?

Comment: Does it work if you use the final (redirect) url as actual starting url? ie: `urlLoader.load(https://edge-01.example. ...etc)` ? If yes, then your solution is to **use final url** always. Maybe the Edge security measures stop such a re-direct feature. For workaround : Since your app is running in browser, could you not get same data into `urlLoader` via something like PHP?

Comment: It's CDN logic to find the best server able to process my request and return that final url then. There's no other way to know it on client side but to receive from CDN.

Comment: Do you know PHP? You could try using `urlLoader` to load the PHP file where the PHP file itself gets & returns (echo) the redirected content. For that consider either `cURL` (with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to true) or even try `file_get_contents`...

Comment: PS: If possible you should add an [**update**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40136156/edit) with a testable link for others to check your problem.